# How to insert today's date in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using PHP and MySQL. My sql query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ocn.newsletter
            (newsletter_name,
             newsletter_subject,
             newsletter_email_body,
             newsletter_call_to_action_status,
             newsletter_call_to_action_text,
             newsletter_call_to_action_link,
             newsletter_created_date)
VALUE      ('Ramzan ID',
            'Ramzan Greetings',
            'Happy Ramzan Eid to All',
            '0',
            '',
            '',
            From_unixtime(Curdate()) )
```

I want to store todays date in UNIX Timestamp format. If I execute above query I'm getting 1970 stored into the table. Actually I want to store UNIX timestamp equivalent of today's date. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in  advance.

Comment: It's `VALUES` with an `S`.

Comment: its depends on your requirement, if you want to store UNIX time just use NOW() in query, or if you want custom Date store in a variable date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); and insert variable in query.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `NOW()` function in your my sql query

`NOW()`,`CURDATE()`,`CURTIME()`

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` usually works in SQL statements / queries and returns the date and time.

```
INSERT INTO ocn.newsletter
            (newsletter_name,
             newsletter_subject,
             newsletter_email_body,
             newsletter_call_to_action_status,
             newsletter_call_to_action_text,
             newsletter_call_to_action_link,
             newsletter_created_date)
VALUES      ('Ramzan ID',
            'Ramzan Greetings',
            'Happy Ramzan Eid to All',
            '0',
            '',
            '',
            NOW() )
```

Alternatively, you can also use the PHP's built-in `time()` function.

```
$timestamp = time(); //1374821956
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use unix_timestamp() function in order to achieve this. This will automatically insert UNIX timstamp equivalent for todays date. The corrected query will be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO OCN.newsletter(newsletter_name, newsletter_subject, newsletter_email_body, newsletter_call_to_action_status, newsletter_call_to_action_text, newsletter_call_to_action_link, newsletter_created_date) VALUE('Ramzan ID', 'Ramzan Greetings', 'Happy Ramzan Eid to All', '0', '', '', unix_timestamp())
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO OCN.newsletter(newsletter_name, newsletter_subject, newsletter_email_body, newsletter_call_to_action_status, newsletter_call_to_action_text, newsletter_call_to_action_link, newsletter_created_date) VALUE('Ramzan ID', 'Ramzan Greetings', 'Happy Ramzan Eid to All', '0', '', '', NOW())`

You can set the default value to your 'newsletter_created_date' to TIMESTAMP if you use MYSQL, and when you did an insert, the TIMESTAMP is automatically set

Comment: If I use NOW() it i entering year 2013 only instead of a whole unix timestamp equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

$query_auto = "INSERT INTO tablename (col_name, col_date) VALUE ('DATE: Auto CURDATE()', CURDATE() )";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this.

```
  $sDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  mysql_query("insert into `ocn.newsletter` set `newsletter_created_date` = '$sDate'");
```